# Finding all images by class name and returning src attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get all the images with class `front` and display their src attribute. Looking at the console it's working, but it returns images with class front and also images with class back along with the entire img code. I only want the src attribute. How can I o about doing this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="results"></div>

<div id="mm_grid">
   <!-- Grid contents written dynamically -->
   <div class="mm_row">
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile0" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image5.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile1" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image5.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_clearfix"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="mm_row">
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile2" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image8.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile3" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image0.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_clearfix"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="mm_row">
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile4" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image3.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_window" id="tile5" onclick="flipImage(this)"><img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image2.jpg" alt="" /><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="mm_clearfix"></div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
var linkArray = $("img.front").map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().html();
}).get();


console.log(linkArray);
```

​
**Results**

```
["<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image5.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">", "<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image5.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">", "<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image8.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">", "<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image0.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">", "<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image3.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">", "<img class="front" src="public/images/mm_image2.jpg" alt=""><img class="back" src="public/images/mm_back.jpg" alt="">"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
return $(this).parent().html();
```

With

```
return $(this).attr('src');
```

In your example you are getting the HTML code of the image parent element (i.e. the div element). This way you get the `src` attribute of the `front` img element alone.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $imgs = $('img.front'),
    arr = [];

$imgs.each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).attr('src'));
});

console.log(arr.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkArray = $("img.front").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

no need to pass through jQuery function inside map()

Answer (score 0):

if you want the SRC attribute only, you have to do the following:

```
$("img.front").each(function (index, element){
   alert($("img.front").eq(index).attr("src"));
});
```

this will print out the SRC of each image with FRONT class.

Comment: Using the index parameter is kind of a waste of code. You could simply write `alert($(this).attr("src"));` which wouldn't ask jQuery to go back and find all the elements matching your selector just to pick a single element which was already passed to the callback function.